# Goodness of fit test for logistic model

Tags: r

I want know what g means and why use Lemeshow goodness of fit (GOF) test in Research ??  and what wrong in "confusion matrix for logistic regression ?
this message :

> Error in confusionMatrix(cnfmat) : 
>     could not find function "confusionMatrix"

```
# ..Binary Logistic Regression :

install.packages("caTools")
library(caTools)
require(caTools)
sample = sample.split(diabetes$Outcome, SplitRatio=0.80)
train = subset(diabetes, sample==TRUE)
test = subset(diabetes, sample==FALSE)
nrow(diabetes) ##calculationg the total number of rows 
nrow(train) ## total number of Train data rows >> 0.80 * 768
nrow(test) ## total number of Test data rows   >> 0.20 * 768
str(train) ## Structure of train set

Logis_mod<- glm(Outcome~Pregnancies+Glucose+BloodPressure+SkinThickness+
                  Insulin+BMI+DiabetesPedigreeFunction+Age,family = binomial,data = train)
summary(Logis_mod)
#AIC .. Akaike information criteria ...
#A good model is the one that has minimum AIC among all the other models.

# Testing the Model
glm_probs <- predict(Logis_mod, newdata = test, type = "response")
summary(glm_probs)
glm_pred <- ifelse(glm_probs > 0.5, 1, 0)
summary(glm_pred)

#Avarge prediction for each of the Two outcomes ..
tapply(glm_pred,train$Outcome,mean)

# Confusion Matrix for logistic regression
install.packages("e1071")
library(e1071)
prdval <-predict(Logis_mod,type = "response")
prdbln <-ifelse(prdval > 0.5, 1, 0)
cnfmat <-table(prd=prdbln,act =train$Outcome)
confusionMatrix(cnfmat)

#Odd Ratio :
exp(cbind("OR"=coef(Logis_mod),confint(Logis_mod)))
```

Comment: `install.packages("caret"); library(caret)`

Comment: Do you have sample data you can include with this question so your error can be replicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what "g" you are referring to, but I'm going to assume it's your resulting computed statistic from your Lemeshow test.  If this is the case then values of "g" indicate how well a model explains the variability in the data and can be used to compare models based on the same set of data (better models will have larger "g" values).

More generally, any goodness of fit (GOF) test in research is used to determine how well your model fits the variability in your data.

Additionally, you are receiving your error because the `confusionMatrix()` function is a part of the `caret` R package.  Install `caret` by first running the below line of code in R or RStudio.

```r
install.packages("caret")
```

Then in your code change

```
cnfmat <-table(prd=prdbln,act =train$Outcome)
confusionMatrix(cnfmat)
```

to

```
cnfmat <-data.frame(prd=prdbln,act =train$Outcome, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
caret::confusionMatrix(cnfmat)
```

Comment: i do that  ```caret::confusionMatrix(cnfmat)```but still theare wrong >>>Error in !all.equal(nrow(data), ncol(data)) : invalid argument type

Comment: looks like `confusionMarix()` reliex on the `nrow` and `ncol` functions which require an input of vector, array, or data.frame.  Try changing `cnfmat <-table(prd=prdbln,act =train$Outcome)` to `cnfmat <-data.frame(prd=prdbln,act =train$Outcome)`.

Comment: @MAJDAHMOBAJER Did this resolve your isses?  If so please select the answer to close out this question.  Best wishes!

Comment: There's something wrong  :: confusionMatrix(glm_pred,di_testing$Outcome)
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
>

Comment: @MAJDAHMOBAJER What version of R are you using?  I've updated the code I posted to include `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` within the `data.frame()` function in case you are not using at least R-4.0.0 (where `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` is now the default).

Comment: R version 3.6.2

Comment: @MAJDAHMOBAJER Try the updated code.  It should overcome issues created by differing factor levels in the two data sets you're trying to combine into one.  As mentioned in my last comment, `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` only became the default with `R-4.0.0`.

Comment: @MAJDAHMOBAJER did this work for you?  If so, please accept the answer so can more easily reference the solution.  Best wishes!

Comment: not work ' i did update R to 4.00 and use the cod stringsAsFactors = FALSE

Comment: my problem in install "carat" rather than "caret" ; thank you @Joshua Mire